# Parseerror on valid json

Tags: jquery, ajax, json

I'm using http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.0/jquery.min.js

I have some trouble with an ajax application :
I get a parse error on json but the json data are valid (I validated it on http://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/)

I have not enough knowledge of jQuery so I'm looking for help :

I'm calling this function :

```
{
    ...

    var jqxhr = $.post(url,{
        month: mois,
        year: annee,
        itemId: gtritemid
        },function(data){
            alert('success');
        }
    );
    return false;
}
```

I declared also ajaxSetup to have some informatioon about what happens :

```
$(function() {
    $.ajaxSetup({
        error: function(jqXHR, exception) {
            if (jqXHR.status === 0) {
                alert('Not connect.\n Verify Network.');
            } else if (jqXHR.status == 404) {
                alert('Requested page not found. [404]');
            } else if (jqXHR.status == 500) {
                alert('Internal Server Error [500].');
            } else if (exception === 'parsererror') {
                alert('Requested JSON parse failed.');
            } else if (exception === 'timeout') {
                alert('Time out error.');
            } else if (exception === 'abort') {
                alert('Ajax request aborted.');
            } else {
                alert('Uncaught Error.\n' + jqXHR.responseText);
            }
        }
    });
});
```

The json is valid so why can't jquery pars the json ?

Comment: what exactly happens in the callback of your post? Which line in there is trowing the error?

Comment: I edited my original post to add the function - since I'm testing I was removing all my normal stuff to be sure that it is not coming from some error there. I left just an alert function. For the line that is throwing the error how can I know this ? All I know is that function(data) seems never to be executed.

Comment: are you trying to get json from different domain than page is on? If so need remote domain to serve jsonp. Willl still see valid json in response body but can't use it due to same origin policy

Comment: json comes from the same site same domain